# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'NoneType' and 'Int'

Tags: python

I am doing past coursework for practice, but I'm not sure what to do.

The task: create a game where the user has to guess a random 4 digit number(no repeated digits).

The problem: my code kind of works - like when you input a number with no repeating digits, it's fine, but when you enter, for example, `1223` I get the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'NoneType' and 'Int'

I have looked online and cannot find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Code below

```
import random
from collections import Counter


def rng():
    num = []
    i = 0
    while i <=3:
        rng = random.randrange(1,9)
        if num.count(rng) == 0:
            num.append(rng)
            i+=1
    return num

def menu():
    userGuesses = 1
    num = rng()#sort out a new num every time
    print(num)
    x = True
    while x == True:
        userExit = input("Would you like to exit(yes or no)")
        if userExit == "yes":
            print("Exiting...")
            exit()
        elif userExit == "no":
            x = False
            over = game(num)
            while over !=True:
                over = game(num)
                userGuesses+=1
            print("Congratulations you got it right, and it only took you ", userGuesses, " guesses!")
            menu()
        else:
            print("Invalid entry")

def userInput():
            userNum = int(input("Please enter a four digit number(no repeated digits)"))
            if(userNum > 1000 or userNum < 9999):
                print("...")
                c = Counter(str(userNum))
                if any(value > 1 for value in c.values()):
                    print ("Your number has repeating digits, please change it.")

                else:
                    x = False
                    return userNum

            else:
                print("Invalid entry")


def convertToArray(userNum):
    userArray = []
    while userNum != 0:
        userNum, x = divmod(userNum, 10)
        userArray.append(int(x))
    userArray.reverse()
    print(userArray)
    return userArray


def check(userArray, num):
    i = 0
    bulls = 0
    cows = 0
    while i<=3:
        if num[i] == userArray[i]:
            bulls +=1
        elif int(userArray[i] in num):
            cows +=1
        i+=1
    print("Bulls:")
    print(bulls)
    print("Cows:")
    print(cows)
    if bulls == 4:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def game(num):
    userNum = userInput()
    userArray = convertToArray(userNum)
    if check(userArray, num) == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False



#Main-----------------------------------------------------------------
print("""Hello and welcome to the game \"Cows and Bulls\":
        *In this game you enter a 4 digit number
        *We compare it to a random number
        *If you get the right number in the right 'place' then you get one bull
        *If you get the right number in the wrong 'place then you get one cow'
        *The game is over when you get 4 bulls, or all the numbers in the right place""")

menu()
```

Comment: may you provide a minimal failing example?

Comment: When `userInput()` reports "Your number has repeating digits" it doesn't return anything, so it returns `None`. Then you call `convertToArray()` with this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - your function doesn't actually return anything because of the print statements, hence an implicit `None` is returned - but there's another solution you can use.

Take advantage of the fact that `userInput` will return `None` if the input isn't valid. Have a condition just before `userArray = convertToArray(userNum)` to check if `userNum` is `None`:

```
def game(num):
    userNum = userInput()
    if userNum is None:
        # Bad input was given
        return False
    userArray = convertToArray(userNum)
    if check(userArray, num) == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def userInput():
        userNum = int(input("Please enter a four digit number(no repeated digits)"))
        if(userNum > 1000 or userNum < 9999):
            print("...")
            c = Counter(str(userNum))
            if any(value > 1 for value in c.values()):
                print ("Your number has repeating digits, please change it.")

            else:
                x = False
                return userNum

        else:
            print("Invalid entry")
```

when userNum is repeated, you return nothing. you should return something and pass it to convertToArray